# Hash code uniqueness for string variable

Tags: java, string, hashcode

in my Event class, it has a `name` variable as a `String`, and I want the `name` to be the unique identifier of an object. In implementing the `hashCode()` method, which way is recommended or right?

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

or

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

Comment: first hashcode == second hashcode + 31. What's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a template when there are **many attributes** (possibly of various types), but if you only have a `String` the default hashCode() defined on `String` (inherited from `Object`) will do fine.

Comment: I have more fields, like boolean, and Long, but the String "name" is going to be the natural and unique identifier.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, then the second one is indeed the most appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You may as well just use the default Java `hashCode` since it works well enough for most purposes. Don't overcomplicate: the second, simpler function will work just fine.